# Insight into Divine Nature of Torah

Tags: proof-of-torah, evidence

I would like to present a very interesting insight which may help people see the divine nature of the Torah. In order of frequency, the following letters appear in the Torah.
Yud (31,531); 
Vav (30513); 
Heh (28056); 
Aleph (27059); 
Mem (25090); 
Lamed (21570)

Although I can't vouch for the exact numbers, the basic phenomenon remains amazing. Just like an artist will hide his name in his painting, Hashem "signed" his name ("YKVK ELKYM"). The odds of this being a random phenomenon are quite minute. Imagine Reuben Bakst being able to supernaturally use R the most, and then E, and then U, etc. - amazing!

Comment: What's the frequency of those letters in Hebrew Harry Potter or something?  You'll probably get similar results.  Hashem did it on purpose, but that doesn't mean it's statistically significant as a proof.

Comment: What are the odds that J.K. Rowling's name is spelled out through Harry Potter books. For example, letter J would be the most frequent letter in the book, and then K, and so on. I HIGHLY doubt you'll find that to be the case. I'd bet my entire worth on that!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  We're a little different from other sites; we're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  While this observation is interesting, I don't see an actual *question* here, so I'm putting this on hold.  You're welcome to [edit] and then users here will review your changes to see if the question can be reopened.  It'd be a good idea for you to first check out our short [tour] to learn more about how the site works.  Thanks.

Comment: I highly doubt that too.  That's not what I said.  If you look in HEBREW Harry Potter you will probably find Yud the most common, followed by Vav, Hei, and so on, just like what you find in the Torah.  (If anything yud and vav will be even more common because Israelis like to write everything malei.)  Those letters are the most common because they serve certain grammatical roles.  I think it would be more interesting to look at why Hashem's name is built out of letters that serve those roles rather than just counting.